# What is wrong with my for /f statement

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

Can someone please explain what is wrong with my for statement? I'm trying to run it as a bat file. I've looked at various examples online and I can't seem to figure out why I get a syntax error

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A in (c:\scripts\destination.txt) DO 
(
echo inside the for loop
pause
)
```

I get the following error:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
>   C:\Scripts>FOR /F "tokens=*" %A in (c:\scripts\destination.txt) DO

Comment: If Foxidrive's answer works for you, be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parenthesis has to be on the same line.

`tokens=*` removes leading whitespace - the `delims=` doesn't.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A in (c:\scripts\destination.txt) DO (
echo %%A - inside the for loop
pause
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I just found this out after a lot of trial and error on my PC. You have no idea how frustrating this was.